# Definition of Angular Momentum of a Particle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum

Lets us consider a Cartesian coordinate system $OXYZ$. The angular momentum $\textbf{L}$ of  a particle with respect to the origin $O$ is given by 
$$\textbf{L} = \textbf{r} \times \textbf{p}$$
where $$\textbf{p} = m \frac{d\textbf{r}_O}{dt},$$
$\textbf{r}_O$ is the position vector of the particle with respect to $O$.

Now I want to determine the angular momentum of the same particle in same coordinate system but with respect to point $O'$. So, 
$$\textbf{L}_{O'} = \textbf{r}_{O'} \times \textbf{p}.$$

**Question:** Then which following one is the correct expression for $\textbf{p}$ in the equation above?

$$\textbf{p} = m \frac{d\textbf{r}_O}{dt}$$ or, 
$$\textbf{p} = m \frac{d\textbf{r}_{O'}}{dt} ? $$

Here, $\textbf{r}_{O'}$ is the position vector of the particle with respect to $O'$.

Comment: take your first two expressions and substitute $\vec{r}\Rightarrow\vec{r}+\vec{oo'}$

Comment: I tried to grasp the nice example at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104784/68036 and it made me think the change of coordinate system should be applied to all the vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula is the second one. However, if point $O'$ is not moving with respect to $O$ then you will find that 
$$ \frac{d\vec{r}_{O}}{dt} = \frac{d\vec{r}_{O'}}{dt}$$
 so it doesn't matter which you use.

To see this consider the following: we know that 
$$ \vec{r}_O(t) = \vec{r}_{O,O'} + \vec{r}_{O'}(t) $$ 
where $\vec{r}_{O,O'}$ is the vector from $O$ to $O'$. Then 
$$ \frac{d\vec{r}_O}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} (\vec{r}_{O,O'} + \vec{r}_{O'}(t)) = \frac{d\vec{r}_{O'}}{dt} $$

If point $O'$ is moving then you should definitely use the second formula.